# Create/deploy REST API using ArcGIS/Python

Tags: python, arcgis-rest-api

I've written a bit of Python code that utilizes ArcGIS to perform some analysis on a specific location. Running this locally on my computer works great. However, I am struggling and am unfamiliar with how to deploy the code as a REST API that I can access through a website.

What is the best or easiest tool to get this done? I've read about some more complex features of ArcGIS such Enterprise version which costs tens of thousands of dollars a year, but that hardly seems reasonable for a tiny one man passion project.

High level I would want the process to be:
1) User inputs address into website using REST API
2) GIS & Python code runs (utilizing ArcGIS scripting tools and some data)
3) Returns to user the results of the analysis through the website.

Comment: Unfortunately, the license agreement for ArcGIS does state that Desktop scripts cannot be deployed as web solutions without an ArcGIS Server license.  It's trivially easy to publish scripts through Server, but there aren't any student/personal/evaluation versions of Server.  You'll probably need to re-architect this solution in open-source tools.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for which open source program to use? I don’t think the GIS portion is too complex; some intersects, buffers, data filtering etc. Is there any work around using ArcGis online? From my reading the primary difference with online and enterprise is just online used ArcGIS infrastructure, which is completely not an issue for my purposes.

Comment: If ArcGIS Online is an option, then you should probably look at that. I don't do software recommendations, except in my professional role (and even then it isn't comparing stacks, just how to architect the Esri stack for so many thousand requests per day)